# ASP.NET 5 + MVC 6 + Web API controller with PUT or PATCH verbs returns 404 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, config.json

I have a basic Web API controller built in MVC 6 (beta 3) as part of a new ASP.NET project. The problem I’ve come across is that it doesn’t accept the verbs PUT or PATCH and returns an error 404 whenever I try to access a URL with those methods.

Here’s what I’ve got as a basic test:

```cs
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string TestGet()
        {
            return "Hello from GET!";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string TestPost()
        {
            return "Hello from POST!";
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public string TestDelete()
        {
            return "Hello from DELETE!";
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public string TestPut()
        {
            return "Hello from PUT!";
        }

        [HttpPatch]
        public string TestPatch()
        {
            return "Hello from PATCH!";
        }
    }
}
```

Visiting `http://localhost/api/test` with 'Postman' to check the URL with each of the verbs (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, and PATCH) in turn works fine for GET, POST, and DELETE, but gives a 404 with PUT and PATCH.

**Edit:**
<s>I remember there being a way of enabling these verbs for MVC5 and lower that involved disabling WebDAV and adding handlers for the two verbs via `web.config`, but as there’s no such thing as `web.config` in ASP.NET 5 I’m at a total loss as to how to fix this. I’m assuming it’s probably solved via `config.json` but all my attempts to search for this have returned nothing helpful at all!</s>

A previous site I developed in MVC5 doesn’t have this problem, and having looked at the `web.config` file there doesn’t appear to be anything in there that disables WebDAV (it’s actually uninstalled) or allows handling of PUT/PATCH methods for extensionless URLs. So I don’t think that what I wrote previously applies.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Web.config still exists and required for IIS

Comment: Despite not changing anything in my code, it appears to be working fine this morning. I am going to put this down to being a bug somewhere as there’s no reason why it shouldn’t have worked before and suddenly started working now.

Comment: It is strange that above code just works fine for every verb for me.

Comment: It seems very intermittent for me. Sometimes it works fine, but then other times it’ll fail and give me a 404 error. I’m guessing there must be a bug somewhere in either the Roslyn compiler or IIS Express as it seems that just restarting the site in IIS Express usually fixes it. It’s a minor pain, but at least there wasn’t anything wrong with my code!

Comment: Closing by author's request.

Answer (score 2):

web.config support is only removed from the .NET and ASP.net part of the app. If your application is hosted in IIS, you still need a web.config just like you did for web API.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I put the ```web.config``` in my project? If I put it in the root of the project, then it won’t get copied across when publishing it, but if I put it in ```wwwroot``` then won’t it either overwrite the ```web.config``` created by publishing or get overwritten by it? Or do I have to manually add the file after publishing? If so, is there a simple way of getting VS2015 (using CTP6 at the moment) to append these settings automatically so I don’t have to do it manually every time I publish my site?

Comment: I’ve edited my question as I no longer believe that the problem in related to a ```web.config``` setting as a previous project developed in MVC 5 didn’t require any special settings and worked fine with PUT/PATCH verbs.